# How to access variables in application.properties file

Tags: java, spring

In the java 15 project I have file application.properties of yml type:

```
NetanyaInfo:
    HydrantPoints: https://www.data.com/
```

I need to use suiteUrlin in the function:

```
 public String getHydrantPoints() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .GET()
            .uri(URI.create(suiteUrl))//here
            .build();


    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return response.body();
}
```

My question is how to get suiteUrl value from the java function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some options available for this in spring. You can use any of them.

Injecting org.springframework.core.env.Environment to your bean.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...

public String getTridelSuites() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .GET()
            .uri(URI.create(env.getProperty("suiteUrl");))//here
            .build();


    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return response.body();
}
```

Comment: This is the _least_ preferable option. Better is to use `@Value` on a constructor parameter or to use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is `spring-boot`, you do not need anything "special", it will be done for you under the hood. What you do is:

- define that `application.properties/yaml` in `src/main/resources`
- inject that value (almost) anywhere you want

For example:

```
 @Value("${tridelInfo.siteUrl}")
 private String siteUrl;
```

or even inside any bean, via a constructor:

```
@Bean/@Service/@Component
public class YourBean {

       private final String siteUrl;   

       public YourBean(@Value("${tridelInfo.siteUrl}") String siteUrl) {
            this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
       }       
}
```

---

Under the hood, you actually need to define a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, but `spring-boot` does that for you.